# Changing $index value while ng-repeat in looping

Tags: angularjs, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat

While using for loop i can do the following

```js
for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
  if(i==2)
  {
    for( i=2;i<=5;i++){
     console.log(i);
    }
  }else{
     console.log(i);
  }
}
```

can I do the same thing in ng-repeat using $index by changing $index value??

Comment: why you want to play with `$index`? what is use case to do that?

Comment: I wish to repeat some part of list in one div only and not every element as a new div

Comment: **Short Answer: No.** `$index` can't be changed on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular.foreach when you want to perform this above operation in controllerjs

```
var items=[0,1,2,3]
 angular.forEach(items,function(item,i){
if(i===2 && i<==5)
  {      console.log(i);

  }else{
     console.log(i);
  }
});
```

if you want to do it in htm

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<span ng-show="$index===2 && $index>=5">Some data </span>
<span ng-show="!($index===2 && $index>=5)">Some data </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do something like this.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.arrOne = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
$scope.arrTwo = [0,1,2,3,4];
})
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
   
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div ng-repeat="items in arrOne" ng-init="parentIndex = $index"> 
  <div ng-if="parentIndex === 2" ng-repeat="itemch in arrTwo | limitTo: (arrTwo.length - parentIndex) : parentIndex ">   {{itemch}}
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      $scope.items.push({id: i, name: 'name' + i});
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
 <ul ng-repeat='item in items' ng-init='temp=$index'>
   <li>     
      <!--if(i==2){for(i = 2; i <= 5; i++)}-->
      <span ng-if='temp==2' ng-repeat='item in items | limitTo : (5 - 2 + 1) : 2'>
         {{item | json}}
      </span>
      <!--else{}-->
      <span ng-if='temp!=2'>{{item | json}}</span>      
   </li>   
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
```